# Databricks: AnalysisException: The specified properties do not match the existing properties at /mnt/product1/data/snapshot/ATM/latest

Tags: databricks, delta-lake

Getting exception while creating Delta Lake Table for existing delta format data:

```
Query: 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS AccountMember USING DELTA  TBLPROPERTIES (delta.enableChangeDataFeed = true, delta.autoOptimize.optimizeWrite = true) LOCATION '/mnt/product1/data/snapshot/ATM/latest'
```

Exception: AnalysisException: The specified properties do not match the existing properties at /mnt/product1/data/snapshot/ATM/latest

Please help to understand the root cause!